# what is major difference between dotnet publish and dotnet pack

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

What is the major difference between dotnet `pack` and `publish`?

From [Microsoft's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet), my understanding is that `pack` creates a package while `publish` creates package + DLL.

Is this correct? 
If so, why not just always use `publish` and not use the DLL file if it is not needed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`dotnet pack` - *Produces a NuGet package of your code.*

That is the key difference - this will enable to publish to http://nuget.org, or to a nuget server that can be pulled down by other developers, or even for use with Octopus Deploy.

`dotnet publish` - *Produces a .NET framework-dependent or self-contained application.*

Keyword is "self-contained", a installer perhaps, or a folder that can be deployed by copying/pasting between hosts.

Comment: jsut to clarify `"self-contained"` here implies inclusion of the executable. That's the part which actually makes it `copy-pastable` and executable just by `copy-paste`.Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, *compiles the application, reads through its dependencies specified in the project file, and publishes the resulting set of files to a directory*

Answer (score 12):

Adding to [the answer by @t0mm13b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44120118):

`dotnet pack`: The output is a package that is **meant to be reused** by other projects.

`dotnet publish`: The output is mean to be deployed / "shipped" - it is not a single "package file" but a directory with all the project's output.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when we use the `pack` command, it creates a package; when we use the `publish` command, it creates a folder that can be copied and executed from anywhere.

What makes `pack` command unique is that the package gets updated to the nuget server without uploading its dependencies. Its dependencies are updated in the project which fetches the package when we run `dotnet restore`. This is not with the case of `dotnet publish`, as it contains third-party dependencies packed in the bundle.